# PHP overriding AJAX post request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, tags, tag-it

On my Code I have this callback

```
 $('#tagList').tagit({
            //Every new dag will be pushed in the list array
            tagsChanged: function(tagValue,action,element){
                list.push(tagValue);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "dostuff.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data:{ items:list.join("::")},
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#wrap').append(data);
                    }
                });
            }
         });
```

What it does it that each time I add a tag the newly added tag will be pushed in the array and after that it will make an AJAX post request.

And Then i have these field here

```
<form method = "POST" action = "demo3.php">
News Title <input id = "news_title" type = "text" name = "news_title" /><br>
    <label>Insert Some tags </label>
    <ul id="tagList" data-name="demo2">
    </ul>
        <input type = "submit" name = "submit" id = "submit" value = "Post News" />
</div>
</form>
```

and when I click the submit(it basically reloads the page) the $_POST['items'](This was created on AJAX request everytime a new tag is added) is being erased or removed in the POST global array. and therefore leaving my $_POST global array empty.

Is there anyway I can merge these two? or anyway not to let PHP override or remove the `$_POST['items']` ?since  I would be needing items for my query

Also I am using a plugin called tagit

If you guys are interested here's my whole code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="demo/js/jquery.1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="demo/js/jquery-ui.1.8.20.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/tagit.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tagit-stylish-yellow.css">
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var list = new Array();
         $('#tagList').tagit({
            //Every new dag will be pushed in the list array
            tagsChanged: function(tagValue,action,element){
                list.push(tagValue);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "dostuff.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data:{ items:list.join("::")},
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#wrap').append(data);
                    }
                });
            }
         });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrap">
<div class="box">
<button class = "viewTags">View Tags</button>
<form method = "POST" action = "demo3.php">
News Title <input id = "news_title" type = "text" name = "news_title" /><br>
    <label>Insert Some tags </label>
    <ul id="tagList" data-name="demo2">
    </ul>
        <input type = "submit" name = "submit" id = "submit" value = "Post News" />
</div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's dostuff. php

```
 <?php 

        $lis = $_POST['items'];
        $liarray = explode("::", $lis);
        print_r($liarray);
        print_r($_POST);
 ?>
```

Comment: PHP doesn't "override" $_POST. What you get into $_POST is what PHP received. If $_POST is empty, then you didn't send anything over, or it's incorrectly formatted.

Comment: Ohh I see. how would I merge the POST request made by ajax and POST received by PHP? since I would be needing them both.

Comment: That makes no sense. you're asking "how do I merge the present my grandma send with the present I received from my grandma"? Unless your code is hosed, there would be one SINGLE http request initiated by your JS code, performing one SINGLE post to your server-side php script.

Comment: My problem here is that the $_POST is acting weird. when I don't click the Submit the $_POST['items'] are in there but when I click submit. nothing is happening only $_POST['news_title'] and $_POST['submit'] s in there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way PHP handles requests are that every request is completely separated from every other one, this sometimes referred as the share nothing architecture. This is the reason of that the request generated from the `<form>` to `demo3.php` doesn't know about the other requests sent by ajax to `dostuff.php` is this separation. This is not necessarily php specific, it's because the underlying [HTTP protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/) is stateless.

If you want to include tags into the request generated when your `<form>` is submitted you need to add those values to the form. For this, the tagit library has a built in way controlled by two config option:

1. [itemName](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it#itemname-string) controls what the parameter named (defaults to `item`)
2. [fieldName](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it#fieldname-string) controls what the field in the `itemName` gets called (defaults to `tags`)

If you initialize your plugin like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S3xdC/1/) without styles):

```
$('#tagList').tagit({
    itemName: 'article',
    fieldName: 'tags'
});
```

Then on submit, the parametes sent down to php should be in `$_POST['article']['tags']`, the parameter names generated will look like `article[tags][]`. See the [demos](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/examples.html) of the plugin. (the page source has nicely formatted javasript examples). By default simply calling `$('#tagList').tagit();` without all the extra callbacks or configuration should work.

This is how it should show up in the net panel of firebug (never mind the demo4.php not beeing there)
[image: shot of firebug net panel after hitting submit]

---

If you want to do it manually you can hook into the `submit` event of `<form>` like this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
    var $form = $(this), 
        tags = $('#tagList').tagit('assignedTags'); // see the docs https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown#assignedtags
    $.each(tags, function(i, tag){
        $('<input type="hidden" name="tags[]">').attr('value', tag).appendTo($form); // using jquery to create new elements
    });
});
```

By using the [assignedTags](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown#assignedtags) method (with jquery ui calling schema) of the tagit plugin, you can get the tag names, and simply add a new hidden input just before submitting the `<form>`. Joining them together like this might be a bad idea if your can include any string imaginable even `::`.

In the example, i've used separate input for each tag so in your `demo3.php` they will arrive as an array (ending the name with `[]` makes php do that).

Comment: Wow it did add the tag! but the it echoed this " Array ( [0] => [object HTMLUListElement] )"

Comment: I'm confused, what echoed that?

Comment: Right after the I submitted the form I used print_r on PHP r. it showed this " Array ( [news_title] => [submit] => Post News [tags] => Array ( [0] => [object HTMLUListElement] ) )" how do I show the values of [0] => [object HTMLUListElement]

Comment: I think you misspelled the a `tag` to a `tags` somewhere. However, tagit plugin has built in method of creating hidden inputs. I've updated. the answer.

Comment: I've changed my code with your new answer. but when I submitted the form it still didn't read the $_POST['article']['tag'] what am  I doing wrong? here's my code http://jsfiddle.net/bFJ2q/1/

Comment: I've forked your fiddle, and added some extra resources to make the plugin load, you can play with it here http://jsfiddle.net/S3xdC/1/ (added to the answer too)